# CAN communication between arduino and raspberry pi

Tags: python, arduino, c, can-bus

I am trying to communicate between Raspberry Pi and Arduino. In arduino I am using this program to transmit

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <mcp_can.h>

const int spiCSPin = 10;

MCP_CAN CAN(spiCSPin);

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(115200);

   while (CAN_OK != CAN.begin(CAN_125KBPS))
    {
        Serial.println("CAN BUS init Failed");
        delay(100);
    }
    Serial.println("CAN BUS Shield Init OK!");
unsigned char stmp[8] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
   
void loop()
{  
  Serial.println("In loop");
  CAN.sendMsgBuf(0x43, 0, 8, stmp);
  delay(1000);
}
```

In Raspberry pi I am using this program to recieve

```
import time

can_interface = 'can0'
bus = can.interface.Bus(can_interface,bustype='socketcan'
while True:
 message = bus.recv()
 print(message)
 time.sleep(1)
```

All I get is

```
Timestamp: 1607187085.129426        ID: 0020    S                DLC:  8    00 19 00 01 03 01 04 01     Channel: can0
```

Everytime I get the same value. What should I do to get the values from arduino to raspberry pi
Thanks!

Comment: Try adding a bitrate parameter to can.interface.Bus in RPi script and set it to 115200. Also, you can remove the time.sleep(1) since bus.recv() is blocking.

Comment: The Pi code is incomplete.

Comment: @A6EE I tried with bitrate as well sir!

Comment: @joan what shld I do to complete sir?